# Result count in SEDE doesn't match with Stack Exchange's API

Tags: stackexchange-api

I queried Stack Exchange explorer with [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1317834) query and got the result of 12946, and I am trying to bring same count of question count through Stack Exchange API:

```
@concat('search/advanced?page=',dataset().PageNumber,'&pagesize=100&fromdate=1561939200&todate=',current date,'&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)5aShmihVOxZoyNN9TVy065dCekm','&q=',dataset().TagsList)
```

However, the API result return onlys ~7000 questions not 12000+.
Base API without the `q` parameter: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1561939200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!)5aShmihVOxZoyNN9TVy065dCekm

Note:
I am using until activity in Azure Data Factory to retrieve all the question that meets the following tags and I am increasing the page number if the `has_more` in the response is `true`.

I am passing two batch of tags as there is a limitation in the `q` filter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) is updated weekly (FWIW, the count is now 13k+). Therefore, the fact that the count of questions tagged with a specific tag differs is reasonable. See [the FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) for more details.

You may also be counting the same questions twice or even three times! Make sure you put its item of the `items` array in a new array and filter the duplicate ones out.

Comment: is there a way we can pull the data from Data Explorer programatically ?.

Comment: Can I use this api https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/query_id in code to get the csv data and then I parse it?